# How to return Future of Either[Throwable,Int] from a Scala Slick Query output

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

I am a beginner in scala , I am using `slick` and `postgres` for one of my `model API`
Below is my function that takes `Id: String` as input and forms a `left inner join query` which returns `matching Ids(String) from DB table`.

```
def getCountByID(
    Id: String
  ): Future[Either[Throwable, Int]] = {
    val innerJoin = for {
      (rel,a) <- executors joinLeft executors on ( (e1, e2) => {
    e1.column1 === e2.column1 && e1.column2 === e2.column2
    } ) if rel.id === Id
  } yield a.map(_.id)

  db.run(innerJoin.result) # Seq of options => FixedSqlStreamingAction[Seq[Option[String]],Option[String],dbio.Effect.Read]

  }
```

The `db.run` gives me a  `Seq of options` . I want to return a `Future` with `Either` `length` of `Ids` or some `throwable exception` . How can I achieve the same here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `Either[Throwable, Int]` is basically a poorer version of `Try[Int]` so I strongly suggest using `Try` here. You can call `asTry` on `result` and you will get `Future[Try[Seq[_]]`:

```
db.run(innerJoin.result.asTry)
```

If you want a count then you should do that in the database rather than outside:

```
db.run(innerJoin.length.result.asTry)
```

This should give `Future[Try[Int]]`.

If you really need `Future[Either[Throwable, Int]]` then you can call `toEither` on the `Try`.

Comment: `db.run(innerJoin.length.result.asTry)` this make perfect sense. I was rather trying to get the count outside.